# How to reuse one modal with different id(Bootstrap)

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I would like to ask how to make this modal reusable for different IDs without looping for example: I have 10 buttons. The bolded text **HERE** is where the IDs should be.

```html
<button type="button" id="1" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#1"></button>
```

And so on until the 10th ID. Is there a way like jQuery/ajax to do it? If so help is greatly appreciated!

```html
<div class="modal fade" id="**HERE**" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-   labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Add resource</h4>
            </div>
            <form action="InsertResServlet" method="POST">
                <div style="width:250px; margin:0 auto;" class="modal-body">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Name</label><br/>
                        <div style="alignment-adjust: middle" class="btn-group">
                            <input type="hidden" name="username" value="**HERE**"/>
                            <input type="hidden" name="projid" value="the ID"/>
                            <select name="empname">
                                <!--some data from database here-->
                            </select>
                        <br/><br/><label>Effort</label>
                        <input type="number" name="effort" min="0" max="1" step="0.1" value="0" required="required"/>
                        <br/><br/><label>Date</label>
                        <input type="text" name="date" required="required" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-danger" value="ADD"/>
                </div>
            </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for a remote modal.

```
<a data-toggle="modal" href="remote.html" data-target="#modal">Click me</a>
```

Basically what it does is it inject the content into `.modal-content` You can use PHP to load your content.